# Memory leak while setListener

Tags: java, android

Memory leak in below example.

1.SpeedHelper.java:

```
public class SpeedHelper {

    interface Listener {
        void OnSelected(String entry);
    }
    static Listener sListener;

    static void setListener(Listener listener) {
        sListener = listener;
    }
    static Listener getListener() {
        return sListener;
    }
    static void clearListener() {
        sListener = null;
    }
}
```

2.CallSpeed.java

```
public class CallSpeed {

    protected void speed() {
        SpeedHelper.Listener litener = SpeedHelper.getListener();
        if (litener != null) {
            litener.OnSelected("mEntry");
        }
    }
}
```

3.MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private CallSpeed callspeed;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SpeedHelper.setListener(mCallSpeedListener);
        callspeed = new CallSpeed();
        callspeed.speed();
    }
    private SpeedHelper.Listener mCallSpeedListener = new SpeedHelper.Listener() {

        @Override
        public void OnSelected(String entry) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), entry, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        SpeedHelper.clearListener();
    }
}
```

How to avoid Memory leak for "sListener"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies in the following non-static enclosed anonymous class in association with the static field `sListener`:

```
private SpeedHelper.Listener mCallSpeedListener = new SpeedHelper.Listener() {

        @Override
        public void OnSelected(String entry) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), entry, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
```

Because this is a non-static enclosed class, it contains a reference to its outer class, `MainActivity`.  This hidden reference blocks the release of the `MainActivity` class by the GC because the object `mCallSpeedListener` - which contains the hidden reference - get stored in the static field `sListener` with the instruction `SpeedHelper.setListener(mCallSpeedListener);`.  Therefore, the `MainActivity` object is never collected, its `onDestroy` function is never called and everything remains in memory; out of reach of the GC.  Using static fields is a door wide open to memory leaks and the presence of hidden references in enclosed classes (anonymous or not) amplifies this problem.

In your case, you will have to either remove the static field `sListener` or change the anonymous class to an ordinary class; one without the hidden reference to its outer `MainActivity` class or make a direct call to `clearListener` in another callback of the activity when it is terminated.

Comment: "make a direct call to clearListener in another callback of the activity when it is terminated", i did not get this.

Comment: private SpeedHelper.Listener mCallSpeedListener = new SpeedHelper.Listener() {
    
            @Override
            public void OnSelected(String entry) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), entry, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            `SpeedHelper.clearListener();
            mCallSpeedListener = null;`
            }
        };

is it correct??

Comment: Sorry for my comment about using something else than onDestroy like onStop or onPause; it was late in the night and onDestroy is not really tied to the GC process: it will be called even if the GC cannot collect the activity's memory.  How did you make the determination that there was a memory leak for sListener?

Comment: Having a item not beeing immediately collected is not a memory leak.  It make take some time and more than one passe of the GC to collect an item.

Comment: You mean to say there is no memory leak in above example.

Comment: Yes, exactly.  You take the precaution of nullifying the static value in the onDestroy event, so it's OK.  However, you should be aware that the use of static variables is a very risky process; for example, take a look at http://www.curious-creature.org/2008/12/18/avoid-memory-leaks-on-android/

Comment: Another great resource for using the MAT when you think you have a leak is https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/fixing-memory-leaks-android-studio-albert-lai

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `static WeakReferences<Listener> sListener` for variable definition in your  `SpeedHelper` class and change your getter and setter methods to:

```
static void setListener(Listener listener) {
    sListener = new WeakReference(listener);
}
static Listener getListener() {
    return sListener.get();
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this will be sufficient: if you don't also put a strong reference on it, the object sListener might be collected by the GC while you still need it.  However, if you add a strong reference from the MainActivity object to the sListener object, then you won't need this static reference anymore at all.